# Bash CLI with HTTParty and rails to handle multiple headers one of which includes a slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, bash, httparty

The following connects to the API's server

```
httparty -a post -H Content-Type:application/json "https://test.co.uk/interface/search"
```

and returns an error message (which is by design).

However, if another header is added:

```
httparty -a post -H Content-Type:application/json -H Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate  "https://test.co.uk/interface/search"
```

an error occurs in the ruby JSON parser

```
.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156:in 
`parse': 765: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)
```

No amount of escaping with quotes changes the situation.

```
httparty -a post -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate  "https://test.co.uk/interface/search"
```

same error...

On the other hand, if one excludes the 'application/json' header, multiple headers can be submitted, obtaining a server response (same error message from API server).

```
httparty -a post -H Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate -H Content-Length:578 -H Host:test.co.uk -H Connection:Keep-Alive "https://test.co.uk/interface/search"
```

How can multiple headers be submitted, with the 'application/json' string pass ruby's JSON parsing filter?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use [HTTPie](https://httpie.org), try to curl like this way.

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate" \
-H "Content-Length:578" \
-H "Host:test.co.uk" \
-H "Connection:Keep-Alive" \
-X POST \
"https://test.co.uk/interface/search"
```

Comment: had tried that... but the API actually does not digest curl commands as an agent. :(  so for my instance, that is not an avenue.